# How to embbed a daily image rotation?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to have a button in my app that shows a different picture everyday via website and if yes how can be done?

Comment: You're going to have to try something first.

Comment: The reason I "do this" is that when you downvote a question, the site suggests you give some indication as to why.

Comment: Also - you may come to realize that what you're asking for has entirely too many answers.  And even the ones that have been given are not exactly perfect.  For instance, how do you intend to handle when someone is not on a live network connection?  How will your app behave?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. And it's also off-topic, since you are requesting for an algorithm. Therefore it's most likely be downvoted and closed very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Create a server which provides your app the image urls. On button click in your app, request the server for the url of that day's image and load it to the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you going to know the URL for the image:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "your src/url name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You would set the returned value to your `imageView`.

If not its a bit more challenging but not impossible.
Are you going to know exactly what HTML container ID/Class the `<img>` will always be in?

If so you would use an HTML parser to bring in the entire web page, similar to above, then you would scan the parsed HTML for the specific `ID` or `Class` that Image has and return it's SRC/URL.

Hope this helps.